# How do i select 1 new row from SQL table, after every 24 hours

Tags: php, mysqli, cron

I have a SQL table : mytable, as:

```
id     |    val1    |    val2
-----------------------------------
1           a              567
2          zzx            7678
3         gtft             5435
```

Now, i have a php page - magic.php, containing something like:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id='$id'"; // id keeps changing per day(i want this)
$result=mysqli_query($conn, $query);
$data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

echo "Value1 is:".$data['val1']."<br/>";
echo "Value2 is:".$data['val2'];
```

Now i want $query to pick id=1 to start & then next id, after every 24 hours.
And when the rows finish, it loops back to re-start.

I tried lots of thing : sleep(), for/while-loops, output buffering with delay & CRON JOBS.
But no success yet. Any guess, how to achieve this exactly ? Thanks tons in advance, for your valuable time.

Comment: Cron-jobs are your friend

Comment: try having another table where you insert what row the program is on, instead of storing the "state" in the loop or cron job itself.

Comment: Do the values in `mytable` change a lot?

Comment: why the javascript/jquery tags here? Plus, you'll need to elaborate on the fact about why the methods you tried to use did not work for you.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

First, let's find out start `time()` and write it down.

```
$start = 1469804863;
```

Now, let's find the number of rows in that table:

```
$num_rows = mysqli_result(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `mytable` "),0);
```

Now, calculating the difference in days:

```
$delta = (time() - $start) / 86400;
```

Now, let's find out which day we need:

```
$row_number = (int)$delta % $num_rows;
```

That's it! Just select the right row now!

```
$row = mysqli_query("SELECT * FORM `mytable` LIMIT {$row_number}, 1");
```

This way, $row_number will start from 0 and grow like 1,2,3,4 and so on till it reaches the number of rows, then will become 0 again, 1,2,3 and so on, in an endless loop

Now, to keep it short:

```
$num_rows = mysqli_result(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `mytable` "),0);
$row_number = floor((time() - 1469804863) / 86400) % $num_rows;
$row = mysqli_query("SELECT * FORM `mytable` LIMIT {$row_number}, 1");
```

Comment: Awesome logic. Hats OFF :)

Comment: @luna.romania , did it work for you? I thought you might mark my answer a winner if it did